# Batch file throws an error saying The network path was not found

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file created to move a file from one folder to another.

Below is the code i have in the batch file.

```
move \\C:\Users\jane\Desktop\test\from\*.* \\C:\Users\jane\Desktop\test\to\*.*
pause
```

When I run this it gives me an error saying :

> The network path was not found.

Am I doing something wrong syntax wise?

Comment: Do you need the leading \\s?

Comment: I tried it with out the leading \\s.. then i get another error saying The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: i am just trying to move an excel file from one folder to another.. both folders are located on my desktop.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks so much! it worked! :) - Also big thanks for explaining why

Comment: @Vanna would you like to add it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in the code you've posted. First, you don't use `\\` before a local drive. Second, you're moving the list of files from the first parameter to the folder in the second, so the second doesn't get a file specification. Also, you should always quote both parameters in case there's a space in a path or filename.

```
move "C:\Users\jane\Desktop\test\from\*.*" "C:\Users\jane\Desktop\test\to\"
pause
```

If you just want to move a specific file, replace the `*.*` with the actual filename

```
move "C:\Users\jane\Desktop\test\from\test.xlsx" "C:\Users\jane\Desktop\test\to\"
pause
```